# Django filter based on related set

Tags: python, django, django-orm

We have following models:

```py
class House(models.Model):
     pass

class Room(models.Model):
     house = models.ForeignKey(house)
     size = models.IntegerField()
```

We use Django Rest Framework to serialize the house  and its rooms. The issue is that we want to filter the rooms by size. We have a viewset where we define the queryset:

```py
def get_queryset():
    return House.objects.filter(...)
```

things we have tried:

- `House.objects.filter(room_set__size__gte=10)` - but this gives houses with rooms larger than 10, but it does not actually filter out the rooms
- `House.objects.filter().annotate(big_rooms=FilteredRelation('room', condition=Q(room_set__size__gte=10)))` this seemed most relevant but did not have any effect :(

I have also considered using `.extra()` but it seems it is deprecated so not great solution... I know I could use custom sql, however, we use Django rest framework filters and thus it would be quite complicated.

Comment: how your models `House` connects to `Room` can you probide full code?

Comment: sorry, forgot about that :( Its added now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class House(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField(verbose_name='Addr', max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address


class Room(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='room')
    size = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="size meters x2")
```

now if you want to select all houses that have room size greater or equals to 10
you can use
`House.objects.filter(room__size__gte=10).distinct()`

Comment: This gives you the Houses that large rooms. We want to filter the rooms itself. We use django serializer on the houses and rooms and we need to filter the rooms.

Comment: i don't get your problem. If you want to get rooms, use `Room.objects.filter(size__gte=10, house=<House_object_which you want to filter>)`

Comment: That gives you rooms per house. You will have n queries for n houses. We want all of this to happen in one query.

Comment: Room.objects.filter(size__gte=10, house__in=<House_object_list_or_ids>)